# Android Canvas: Draw only part of precalculated Path

Tags: android, android-canvas

Is it possible to draw only part of a Path? Let's say my Path is from x = 0 to x = 2000, the whole Path is calculated on start, and the Canvas is placed on HorizontalScrollView. When scroll x = 500, I want to draw only from 500 to 1000 of that Path; when x = 0 draw 0 to 1000, when x = 1500, draw 1000 to 1500 and when x = 2000 draw 1000 to 2000.

Path is a bezier curve, so if the calculation needs to be done all the time, it's damaging performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution by drawing the whole line, and after that calculate Rect to draw on top of it, to hide particular part on visible part.

[image]

This is to demonstrate how I did this, I am drawing the whole Path, and to get it clip, I draw a rectangle on top of it to right position of screen, so it looks like the path is clipping.

Comment: For this you probably used canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint), right? Where did you insert your Path object on it? I'm facing an similar problem.. Could you please post some piece of that code part?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getSegment` method for this purpose, like this (Kotlin):

```
private fun getSubPath(path: Path, start: Float, end: Float): Path {
    val subPath = Path()
    val pathMeasure = PathMeasure(path, false)
    pathMeasure.getSegment(start * pathMeasure.length, end * pathMeasure.length, subPath, true)
    return subPath
}
```

Usage:

```
val subPath = getSubPath(path = originalPath, start = 0.2f, end = 0.8f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have an answer for you.

The Picture class is used to store pictures that do not change and then write them to a canvas.

For example, you could have 4 different Picture objects, each with part of the Bezier curve, then write them when you want them.

Some code might look something like this:

```
Picture b1 = new Picture();
Canvas c1 = b1.beginRecording(500, height);
// draw
b1.endRecording();
Picture b2 = new Picture();
Canvas c2 = b2.beginRecording(500, height);
c2.translate(-500, 0);
// draw
b2.endRecording();
Picture b3 = new Picture();
Canvas c3 = b3.beginRecording(500, height);
c3.translate(-1000, 0);
// draw
b3.endRecording();
Picture b4; = new Picture();
Canvas c4 = b4.beginRecording(500, height);
c4.translate(-1500, 0);
// draw
b4.endRecording();

(if x < 500) {
    // draw c1
}
...
```

There's probably a way to only draw it once, rather than 4 times, but I'm just posting what I know works. If you can find a way to partition the canvas, then you only need to draw it once.

Comment: This means if my X scale is 2000, I need 2000 pictures, so doesn't seem to fit my purposes here.